# What is the meaning of ~ in aggregate?

Tags: r

```
x <- iris[,1:4]
names(x) <- c("x1","x2","x3","x4")
aggregate(x1+x2+x3+x4~x1,FUN=sum,data=x)
```

Here is the output ,i wonder
1. What is the meaning of `~` in a formula?
2. Why `x1 = 4.3`  ,the `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4`   is 8.5?

x1 x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
1 4.3 8.5
2 4.4 26.9
3 4.5 8.4

when i use

```
 transform(x,x1=sort(x1))
```

what I get is :

```
     x1  x2  x3  x4  
1   4.3 3.5 1.4 0.2  
2   4.4 3.0 1.4 0.2  
3   4.4 3.2 1.3 0.2  
4   4.4 3.1 1.5 0.2
```

（many output omitted)
When  `x1=4.3`  ,the `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4`   is  not  `3.5+1.4+0.2=5.1` ,nor `4.3+3.5+1.4+0.2=9.4`?

Comment: You should also be asking what `+` does in a formula, because while it means a sum, it is not a sum in the way that you are thinking.  To get an actual sum of variables, you would write `I(x1+x2+x3+x4)`.  See `?formula`.

Answer (score 8):

`~` in `aggregate()` separates, to the left side, what is being "aggregated", and to the right side, what is being used to "aggregate" the items.

In your example, the result of `x1 + x2 + x3 + x4` will be calculated for each row, and then summed up according to the group formed by `tuples` in which `x1` appears with the same value.

So, the reason why you have `8.5` is because, the data being summed is:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 = sum(c(4.3, 3.0, 1.1, 0.1)) = 8.5
```

The line with `x1 = 4.3`, in your example, is the 14th row: `14  4.3 3.0 1.1 0.1`.

The values are all summed up, and each resultant sum is aggregated by `x1` value, and sent to `FUN=sum` for being summed.

Since there's only one `x1 = 4.3`, the value will be simply `8.5`, which is the result of the sum of entries from row 14th.

Answer (score 5):

The [tilde operator](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/tilde.html) creates a symbolic formula. Here's an excerpt from a [blog post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-for-introductory-statistics-chapter-3-4/) that explains it better than I could:

> f = price ~ carat
>
> [...]
>
> We start by creating the formula f using the strange looking tilde operator. That tells the R interpreter that we're defining a symbolic formula, rather than an expression to be evaluated immediately. So, our definition of formula f says, "price is a function of carat".

The manual page on [formula](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html)s has more to say about the tilde operator.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second question, in the Iris data set there is only one row where the first column is 4.3.  That row is:

```
(x[x[,1]==4.3,])

#     x1 x2  x3  x4
# 14 4.3  3 1.1 0.1

# and 4.3 + 3.0 + 1.1 + 0.1 = 8.5.

sum(x[x[,1]==4.3,])

# [1] 8.5


# There are four rows where x1 = 6.9.  Those rows are:

x[x[,1]==6.9,]

#      x1  x2  x3  x4
# 53  6.9 3.1 4.9 1.5
# 121 6.9 3.2 5.7 2.3
# 140 6.9 3.1 5.4 2.1
# 142 6.9 3.1 5.1 2.3

# and

# 6.9 + 3.1 + 4.9 + 1.5 +
# 6.9 + 3.2 + 5.7 + 2.3 +
# 6.9 + 3.1 + 5.4 + 2.1 +
# 6.9 + 3.1 + 5.1 + 2.3 = 69.4

sum(x[x[,1]==6.9,])

# [1] 69.4
```

Regarding your new question, I think

```
transform(x,x1=sort(x1))
```

is only sorting the first column and the other columns remain unchanged, in which case you are changing the data set.

4.3+3.5+1.4+0.2=9.4

```
#      x1  x2  x3  x4
# 1   4.3 3.5 1.4 0.2
# 2   4.4 3.0 1.4 0.2
# 3   4.4 3.2 1.3 0.2
# 4   4.4 3.1 1.5 0.2
# 5   4.5 3.6 1.4 0.2
```

If you want to order the data set by increasing values of the first column without changing the data set use:

```
x[order(x$x1),]

#      x1  x2  x3  x4
# 14  4.3 3.0 1.1 0.1
# 9   4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2
# 39  4.4 3.0 1.3 0.2
# 43  4.4 3.2 1.3 0.2
# 42  4.5 2.3 1.3 0.3
```