# How to get the same result in aggregate?

Tags: r

How can i get the result in aggregate?

```
x=iris[,1:4]
transform(x,"sum"=apply(x,MARGIN=1,FUN=sum))
```

the output is :

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width  sum
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 10.2
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  9.5
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  9.4
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  9.4
```

(many lines  omitted),i just want to know aggregate better,maybe it is difficult to get the same result as  apply  by aggregate function.

Comment: you mean the opposite, right?

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. apply and aggregate do completely different things.

Comment: I agree with @joran. You should reformulate your question to articulate  what you're generally trying to achieve. Right now it sounds like you're asking how to fit a square peg into a round hole. If you just want to avoid your call to `apply`, an alternative is `sum=rowSums(x)`.

Comment: apply(x,MARGIN=1,FUN=sum) is the same as rowSums(x).  I do not know how to sum individual rows using aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Rubens is correct and you want to use `apply` instead of `aggregate`, and you are interested in the same `aggregate` expression as in your earlier post of today then you can use `tapply`.

[What is the meaning of ~ in aggregate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078591/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-aggregate)

```
x=iris[,1:4]
names(x)<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4")
aggregate(x1+x2+x3+x4~x1,FUN=sum,data=x)
tapply((x$x1 + x$x2 + x$x3 + x$x4), x$x1, sum)
```

Edited to add `sapply` and `lapply` modified from DWin's answer to give the same answer as `tapply` and
`aggregate` immediately above, as well as `rapply`, `vapply` and a reformatted `tapply` and a `by` function:

```
with(x, sapply(split((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), x1), sum))
with(x, lapply(split((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), x1), sum))
with(x, rapply(split((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), x1), sum))
with(x, tapply(      (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), x1 , sum))
with(x, vapply(split((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), x1), sum, FUN.VALUE=1))
with(x, by((x1 + x2 + x3 + x4), x1, sum))
```

I have not figured out how to get the same answer with `mapply`.  Well, here is one way, but it is pretty silly:

```
tapply(mapply(sum, x$x1 , x$x2 , x$x3 , x$x4), x$x1, sum)
```

Lastly, here is a way to use `apply` (inside `tapply`) to get the same answers as given by the other lines above:

```
tapply(apply((x[,1:4]),1,sum),x$x1,sum)
```

One last thing, if you really do want `aggregate` to return the same answers as the `apply` statement in your post, it is possible.  However, all you are doing is summing each individual row with your `apply` statement.  Therefore, you will have to 'trick' `aggregate` into thinking there is a separate group for each row in the Iris data set like so:

```
x=iris[,1:4]
names(x)<-c("x1","x2","x3","x4")
apply.sums <- transform(x,"sum"=apply(x,MARGIN=1,FUN=sum))
my.factor <- seq(1, nrow(x))
ag.sums <- aggregate(x1+x2+x3+x4~my.factor,FUN=sum,data=x)
round(ag.sums[,2],2) == round(apply.sums[,5],2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems somewhat different than the code that I would have expected to follow. `aggregate` is intended to "apply" a particular function to columns but only within categories demarcated by the "by" argument. It is designed to "aggregate within particular categories.

`apply` (with its second argument set to 2 rather than 1 as in your code) will use a function on entire columns. There is no grouping variable. You coder is being run row by row on vectors of different meaning and import, and so it returns the individual sums of the four disparate measurements for each individual, a process that is arguably meaningless unless some preparation or groundwork for the procedure has been established.

If you wanted to use apply in a manner similar what is achieved with aggregate then look at these:

```
> sapply( split(iris[,1:4], iris[, 5]), apply, 2, sum)
             setosa versicolor virginica
Sepal.Length  250.3      296.8     329.4
Sepal.Width   171.4      138.5     148.7
Petal.Length   73.1      213.0     277.6
Petal.Width    12.3       66.3     101.3


> aggregate(iris[ ,1: 4], iris[5], FUN=sum)
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1     setosa        250.3       171.4         73.1        12.3
2 versicolor        296.8       138.5        213.0        66.3
3  virginica        329.4       148.7        277.6       101.3
```

If your goal were not to do any by-category calculations you would pass aggregate a list of the same length as the number of rows of the dataframe:

```
> aggregate(iris[ ,1: 4], list(rep(1,nrow(iris))),  FUN=sum)
  Group.1 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1       1        876.5       458.6        563.7       179.9
> apply(iris[1:4], 2, sum)
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
       876.5        458.6        563.7        179.9
```

Comment: in the case we use apply in a manner similar as aggregate, do you think we can prefer apply for a preformance reason for example?

Comment: `apply.data.frame` does not generally yield great performance. I would expect approaches using `sapply` or `lapply` to yield better performance. They do less class checking. `colMeans` or `colSums` would be fastest if the questions were fitted to those functions.