# Summarize R data frame based on a date range in a second data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one that includes data by day, and one that includes data by irregular time multi-day intervals. For example:

A data frame `precip_range` with precipitation data by irregular time intervals:

```
start_date<-as.Date(c("2010-11-01", "2010-11-04", "2010-11-10"))
end_date<-as.Date(c("2010-11-03", "2010-11-09", "2010-11-12"))
precipitation<-(c(12, 8, 14))
precip_range<-data.frame(start_date, end_date, precipitation)
```

And a data frame `precip_daily` with daily precipitation data:

```
day<-as.Date(c("2010-11-01", "2010-11-02", "2010-11-03", "2010-11-04", "2010-11-05",
                  "2010-11-06", "2010-11-07", "2010-11-08", "2010-11-09", "2010-11-10",
                  "2010-11-11", "2010-11-12"))
precip<-(c(3, 1, 2, 1, 0.25, 1, 3, 0.33, 0.75, 0.5, 1, 2))
precip_daily<-data.frame(day, precip)
```

In this example, `precip_daily` represents daily precipitation estimated by a model and `precip_range` represents measured cumulative precipitation for specific date ranges. I am trying to compare modeled to measured data, which requires synchronizing the time periods.

So, I want to summarize the `precip` column in data frame `precip_daily` (count of observations and sum of `precip`) by the date date ranges between `start_date` and `end_date` in the data frame `precip_range`. Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the start_dates from `precip_range` as breaks to `cut()` to group your daily values. For example

```
rng <- cut(precip_daily$day, 
    breaks=c(precip_range$start_date, max(precip_range$end_date)), 
    include.lowest=T)
```

Here we cut the values in daily using the start dates in the range data.frame. We're sure to include the lowest value and stop at the largest end value. If we merge that with the daily values we see

```
cbind(precip_daily, rng)

#           day precip        rng
# 1  2010-11-01   3.00 2010-11-01
# 2  2010-11-02   1.00 2010-11-01
# 3  2010-11-03   2.00 2010-11-01
# 4  2010-11-04   1.00 2010-11-04
# 5  2010-11-05   0.25 2010-11-04
# 6  2010-11-06   1.00 2010-11-04
# 7  2010-11-07   3.00 2010-11-04
# 8  2010-11-08   0.33 2010-11-04
# 9  2010-11-09   0.75 2010-11-04
# 10 2010-11-10   0.50 2010-11-10
# 11 2010-11-11   1.00 2010-11-10
# 12 2010-11-12   2.00 2010-11-10
```

which shows that the values have been grouped. Then we can do

```
aggregate(cbind(count=1, sum=precip_daily$precip)~rng, FUN=sum)

#          rng count  sum
# 1 2010-11-01     3 6.00
# 2 2010-11-04     6 6.33
# 3 2010-11-10     3 3.50
```

To get the total for each of those ranges (ranges as labeled with the start date)

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly for getting the sum of precip, but as indicated I also want the count of rows with precip values within each date range. I want this as a check- to make sure I have precip values for each day within the date range.

Comment: Just do `table(rng)` as well.

Comment: Or if it needs to be one call, `aggregate(cbind(count=1, sum=precip_daily$precip)~rng, FUN=sum)`

Comment: Never knew about that! [What is the meaning of ~ in aggregate?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078591/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-aggregate)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
temp <- merge(precip_daily, precip_range, by.x = "day", by.y = "start_date", all.x = T)
temp$end_date <- na.locf(temp$end_date)
setDT(temp)[, list(Sum = sum(precip), Count = .N), by = end_date]

##     end_date  Sum Count
## 1: 2010-11-03 6.00     3
## 2: 2010-11-09 6.33     6
## 3: 2010-11-12 3.50     3
```